# Using wildcard within ArcGIS ModelBuilder to select raster files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, wildcard

I already checked (almost) all other related topics I was not able to figure out how to solve my problem.

I want to process certain rasters in many different subfolders. Within these folders I have also rasters I don't want to process. I want to identify the rasters to process by name. They're all named like `84z93bhjgd_DEM.tif`. I thought that putting `*DEM` into the wildcard field of the iterate rasters menu would solve the problem but it doesn't. Why? Is it not possible to use the `*` in front of the definition?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote it, your wildcard parameter expects something ENDING in DEM. So, you need **either a trailing asterisk**:

`*DEM*` (matches anything before or after 'DEM')

or, as @Hutch mentions, **specify the exact ending** of the string to match:

`*DEM.tif` (matches anything ending in 'DEM.tif')

Comment: I tried with both options but if I use `*DEM*` it processes all tif files in all subdirectories (even if they don't contain the string). I have absolutely no clue why. The option `*DEM.tif` doesn't work either, it processes nothing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate Feature Classes allows for wildcards to be added into your ModelBuilder.

You might be able to go *DEM.tiff.

This documentation may help, it explains Iterate Feature Classes.
https://is.muni.cz/el/1431/jaro2016/Z2011/um/63288329/63288429/Using-ModelBuilder-to-batch-process-files.pdf